# Determine if file is a socket reference in Linux with Perl

Tags: linux, perl

In linux, I can do a stat on a file in the proc directory and determine if it is a socket.

```
root@dev:/proc/2221/fd# stat 100
  File: `100' -> `socket:[125598]'
```

How can I get this same result with perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to know if it is a socket, then:

```
if(-S $file_name) { /* do something */ }
```